# React native onValueChange

Tags: reactjs, react-native, picker

I'm trying to write two functions with onValueChange but it only doing one of them. Is there a way to do it?

```
  import { Picker } from 'react-native';
    <Picker
      selectedValue={selectedValue}
      style={{ height: 35, width: 135 }}
      onValueChange={(todoInput2) => props.textChange(todoInput2)}
      onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedValue(itemValue)}
      >
      
      <Picker.Item label="Resident" value="Resident" />
      <Picker.Item label="Visitor" value="Visitor" />
    </Picker>
```

Comment: Can you add more detail, like what library did you use? Or what's the logic inside the `<Picker` ?

Comment: Before digging into `React Native` or `React`, you should first learn the basics of `JavaScript` (especially `ECMAScript`). `onValueChange={(todoInput2) => { props.textChange(todoInput2); setSelectedValue(todoInput2); }}`

Comment: I'm trying to make a dropdown picker. I tried various things but none of them worked. Can onValueChange take multiple functions?

Comment: My question is: why would you need to do that? Do you want to do multiple things in the same callback function `onValueChange`?

Answer (score 0):

You are using [react-native-picker](https://reactnative.dev/docs/picker) (which by the way is deprecated. You should consider using [@react-native-picker/picker](https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker)).

However, that is not the problem. You can't pass the same `prop` twice, thus writing

```js
<Picker
      onValueChange={(todoInput2) => props.textChange(todoInput2)}
      onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedValue(itemValue)}
 >
```

does not work, since we attempt to pass `onValueChange` twice as a prop to the component.

There is also no `todoInput2` parameter.

> onValueChange
>
> Callback for when an item is selected. This is called with the following parameters:
>
> itemValue: the value prop of the item that was selected
>
> itemPosition: the index of the selected item in this picker

Since you want to execute two functions `onValueChange` you could just write a function and pass this as a prop instead.

```js
function handleValueChange(itemValue, itemIndex) {
   props.textChange(itemValue)
   setSelectedValue(itemValue)
}
```

Then, pass this as a prop.

```js
<Picker
      selectedValue={selectedValue}
      style={{ height: 35, width: 135 }}
      onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => handleValueChange(itemValue)}
      >
      
      <Picker.Item label="Resident" value="Resident" />
      <Picker.Item label="Visitor" value="Visitor" />
    </Picker>
```

Comment: please check my question as well. My question is related to this one

[my question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74430269/how-to-show-the-selected-item-in-picker-component-react-native)